# Converting EXR image sequence to .MOV

Tags: image-processing, quicktime, mov, openexr

I'm looking for a encoder that creates a Quicktime Movie (PhotoJpeg) from OpenEXR image sequences.

Any help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 3):

DJV Imaging 0.7.0 Beta seems to do the trick. you can read it and export it into any kind of format.
http://djv.sourceforge.net/

user 3rdrail does your thing, so look on this site and search for his first post:

http://forums.cgsociety.org/archive/index.php/t-521501.html